# Redhat Openshift MySQL environment variables not set

Tags: php, mysql, openshift

Throughout the documentation for Redhat Openshift, it says that on adding a MySQL cartridge, the following environment variables are automatically set:

```
OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST    
OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT    
OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME    
OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD    
OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_SOCKET
OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_URL
```

But with PHP 5.4 with Zend Server 6.1, MySQL 5.5, and phpMyAdmin 4.0 installed, this code:

```
$dbhost = getenv("OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST");
$dbport = getenv("OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT");
$dbuser = getenv("OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME");
$dbpwd = getenv("OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD");
echo $dbhost . "|" . $dbport . "|" . $dbuser . "|" . $dbpwd;
```

returns this:

```
||||
```

Any ideas as to why these environment variables aren't set/how I can set them. Alternatively, any ideas as to how I could figure out what they should be set to so I can just use that instead would be fine, since it's a very small application (only two php files making MySQL connections, in fact).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try restarting your gear, if you added mysql AFTER you created your gear with zend, that could be the issue. Also take a look at https://www.openshift.com/blogs/zend-server-61-and-php-54-cloud-hosting for an easy get started approach.